# Property or method "buscador" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning laravel with Vue js I am implementing a search engine with vue js components, I hope you can help me in advance thanks.

This is my Vue js component where my input search is located.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <input 
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="buscar"
                type="search"
                v-model="buscador"
                @keyup="buscarProductos" 
            >
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is my app.js file.

```
const { default: Axios } = require('axios');

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    
    created(){
        this.producto();
    },

    data: {
        
        libros:[],
        buscador: '',
        setTimeoutbuscador:''
    },
    methods: {
        producto(){
            
            Axios.get('./sales', {
                params:{
                    filtro: this.buscador
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                this.libros = res.data.data ;
            })
            .catch( error => {
                console.log( error.response )
            });
        },

        buscarProductos(){
            clearTimeout( this.setTimeoutbuscador = setTimeout(this.producto, 360) )
        }

    }
 
});
```

I have a blade view where I place my component in this way.

```
<div id="app">
    <example-component></example-component>      
</div>
```

Comment: Try recompiling with npm run dev or npm run watch and refresh and see. There seems to be no issue with the code

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer, If I have it executing npm run watch, the detail is that at the time of writing in my input my search variable within data does not reflect the result and in the console it shows me the following error The property or method "search engine" is not defined in the instance , but it is referenced during rendering.

Comment: Can you post the complete vue component code - the .vue file

Comment: <template>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <input 
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="buscar"
                type="search"
                v-model="buscador"
                @keyup="buscarProductos" 
            >
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

Comment: it's just a component with an input type search

Comment: And what are the contents of the script section of the component?  If you are trying to access properties defined on the root vue instance in a component you will get error

Comment: Este es codigo completo 

<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <input 
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="buscar"
                type="search"
                v-model="buscador"
                @keyup="buscarProductos" 
            >
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **ExampleComponent.vue** file should look like below

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <input 
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="buscar"
                type="search"
                v-model="buscador"
                @keyup="buscarProductos" 
            >
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Axios from 'axios';

export default {
    
    created(){
        this.producto();
    },

    data(){
        return {
            buscador: ''
        }
    },
    
    methods: {
    
        producto(){
            
            Axios.get('./sales', {
                params:{
                    filtro: this.buscador
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                this.libros = res.data.data ;
            })
            .catch( error => {
                console.log( error.response )
            });
        },

        buscarProductos(){
            clearTimeout( this.setTimeoutbuscador = setTimeout(this.producto, 360) )
        }
    }
}
```

And your **app.js** would be

```js
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent';

Vue.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Then you can use the ExampleComponent as

```html
<div id="app">
    <example-component></example-component>      
</div>
```

Data properties defined on root component cannot be accessed as local properties on a vue component.

Data properties of root component can be accessed as `$root.bucador` for example.

However as far as possible Vue components should be defined as decoupled as possible - it should contain properties required in it's template. For properties required to be passed from parent component they can be passed as props.

Read Vue docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ it has plenty of examples